Squid прокси вместе с OpenVPN на Docker
Установил на контейнер OpenVPN клиент и Squid прокси, хочу гонять трафик по прокси через VPN можете помочь прописать настройки или маршруты чтобы работало это все? Я немного нуб, отдельно оба работают вроде но при включении ВПН до прокси не достучаться.
